# Amcharts 5 stock chart - how to color candles based on position string uploaded in data

Tags: amcharts, stock, candlestick-chart, amcharts5, candlesticks

Attempting to color stock candles based on "inTrade" string included in data. Three states "Long", "Short", "None". Began working with Amcharts 5 "Stock Chart Comparing Prices" demo which now incorporates two data files. One which is 5 days of historical data (15 minute candles) and one which is "live" data within the current 15 minute candle uploaded every 10 seconds.

Historical data format ..

window["Live_minute"] = [
{Date:1680631200000,Open:164.565,High:164.603,Low:164.51,Close:164.598,inTrade:"Short"},
...
]

Live data file format
{"Date":1681318800000,"Open":166.27,"High":166.364,"Low":166.23,"Close":166.347,"inTrade":"Long"}

Tried disabling value dependent coloring and setting up quick theme with no effect.

The string in the data file is formatted correctly ... [Note "position" in legend text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/toHIx.png)

I did try and was able to achieve desired result with Amcharts 4, however I used numeric values (ie "1" represented Long, -1 Short, 0 None) instead of string.

// AMCHARTS 4 PROCEEDURE

```
delete series.riseFromOpenState.properties.fill;
delete series.dropFromOpenState.properties.fill;
series.columns.template.adapter.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  if (target.dataItem && (target.dataItem.customValue < 0)) {
    return am4core.color("#FF0000");
  }
  else
  if (target.dataItem && (target.dataItem.customValue > 0)) {
    return am4core.color("#0094FF");
  }
  else
  if (target.dataItem && (target.dataItem.customValue === 0)) {
    return am4core.color("#C6C6C6");
  }
});
```

I would much rather learn how to do this in Amcharts 5, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

For amCharts 5 you can do something like this

```
series.columns.template.adapters.add("fill", function(fill, target) {
  if (target.dataItem.get("valueY") < 1000) {
    return am5.color(0xff621f);
  }
  else {
    return fill;
  }
});
```

See [here](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v5/concepts/settings/adapters/#adding)